# Can you get jboss weld to continually scan for newly added classes during development?

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld

i'm setting up a JSF2 project on tomcat 6.0.29 with weld. also using jrebel - not sure if that makes a difference.

In testing out JRebel i can see that updating classes that existed when the container was started are handled fine.

however, if i ADD a newly defined CDI component class and re-explode the app without restarting the appserver, i can't access it from the facelets till i restart. JRebel seems to be loading the class in, so i'm guessing weld isn't registering it in the beanmanager

i realise that CDI is meant to hook up the config on startup, but it would be good to have some sort of dev switch to enable continuous scanning the same way JSF has a dev mode that picks up changed facelet templates.

this and the functionality that JRebel provides would be an awesome productivity boost.

can this be done? had a quick look at the weld docs but can't find anything.

thanks.

Comment: the functionality you describe should be implemented by JRebel, the same way it implements similar stuff with hibernate configuration updates in runtime. Otherwise, you are right -- CDI scans config during startup only

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. But adding new beans would be something rare, compared to changing existing ones. And that doesn't require restart.